# Adding a new Value to an already existing Array (not using ArrayList)

Tags: java, arrays

I want to add a new Value to my already existing Array. I made a new Array with the length of the already existing one and added one more Place for the new Value.

```
public class Measurement {

    private int[] data;

    public Measurement() {
        data = new int[0];
    }

    public static void addValue(int value) {
        int [] a = new int [data.length + 1];
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            a[i] = data[i];
            a[i + 1] = value;
        }
        for(int i: a) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried it with an already initialized Array and it worked, but I don't know what it doesn't with my existing try.

```
int[] a = {1,3,4,5,6,9};
        int value = 10;
        int[] b = new int[a.length + 1];
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            b[i] = a[i];
            b[i + 1] = value;
    }
    for (int i : b) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Comment: Your current code wouldn't compile because `addValue` is a static method, and `data` is an instance field.

Comment: Your first  loop will not run even once for empty array as `i < data.length` will be false immediately. meaning `a[i + 1] = value;` will also never run. But i don't see the logic in adding the extra element in the loop anyway. just do `a[a.length-1] = value;` after your loop to add the extra value.

Comment: How can i solve the Problem with a for-loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
public class Measurement {

    private int[] data = new int[0];

    public void addValue(int value) {
        int[] arr = new int[data.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, arr, 0, data.length);
        arr[arr.length - 1] = value;
        data = arr;
    }

}
```

---

Alternative way:

```java
public class Measurement {

    private int[] data = new int[0];

    public void addValue(int value) {
        data = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length + 1);
        data[data.length - 1] = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, so just for me to understand: data = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length + 1); is there to make a new Array with the a new index and with data[data.length - 1] = value; i Am looking at the new created array and adding the new Value to the created extra space?

Comment: @Goof Yes.  Per the javadoc of `copyOf(int[],int)`: "Copies the specified array, truncating or padding with zeros (if necessary) so the copy has the specified length."